# Difference between ordinary parameter, reference parameter and const reference parameter passed by ordinary object and object created temporary

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, constants, const-reference

Since I'm a beginner in c++, some questions don't quite understand. This question came across by accident while I was reading C++ primer 5th.

---

I have a `Cat` class with 3 different constructors(named by Constructor 1, Constructor 2, Constructor 3):

```cpp
class Cat {
    friend class Cats;

private:
    std::string name;

public:
    Cat() = default;

    // Constructor 1
    Cat(std::string n): name(n) {
        std::printf("Call: Cat(std::string n)\n");
    }

    // Constructor 2
    Cat(std::string& n): name(n) {
        std::printf("Call: Cat(std::string& n)\n");
    }

    // Constructor 3
    Cat(const std::string& n): name(n) {
        std::printf("Call: Cat(const std::string &n)\n");
    }

};
```

And I want to instantiate the class in two different ways:

```cpp
class C7T17_Main {
public:
    void run() {

        // Instantiation 1
        Cat cat(std::string("Cathy"));
       
        // Instantiation 2
        std::string s("Mike");
        Cat cat2(s);

    }
};
```

---

Then the problem comes:

- For `Constructor 1`:

  - `Instantiation 1` and `Instantiation 2` both work well
- For `Constructor 2`:

  - `Instantiation 1` raises an error. The compiler complains that *'Candidate constructor not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument'*
  - `Instantiation 2` works normally.
- For `Constructor 3`:

  - `Instantiation 1` and `Instantiation 2` both work well

---

My guess is:

- `Instantiation 1` does not actually create a variable, but a temporary value for initializing cat, so it is not suitable as a reference parameter.
- For `constructor 3`, the const reference parameter represents a constant that can accept a temporary value for initialization

---

Looking forward to your help. :)

Comment: ***'Candidate constructor not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument'*** You get this error, because you passed anonymous string to a function expecting a reference argument. Reference requires the string to be stored in some variable. So your guess is correct.

Comment: You are right. Though MSVC with `/Zc:referenceBinding-` would compile `Constructor 2` too

Comment: ***For constructor 3, the const reference parameter...*** not sure about this, but maybe because the argument expected is a "reference to a const string". Since the value isn't going to be modified, maybe compiler allows it - but not sure.

Comment: @kiner_shah You can always bind a `const` reference to a rvalue (assuming of course the types match). That is just a rule of the language.

Comment: @user17732522, got it thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

1. *ctor 1* receives the argument by copy (pass by **value**);
2. *ctor 2* receives the argument by **non-const lvalue reference**, so it only supports **non-const lvalues**.
3. *ctor 3* receives argument by **const lvalue reference** so it supports **const-lvalue**, **non-const lvalue**, **const rvalue** and **non-const rvalue**.

> Instantiation 1 does not actually create a variable, but a temporary value for initializing cat, so it is not suitable as a reference parameter.

Yes, it creates a **prvalue**, and it can be passed by reference like this:

```
// ctor 4
Cat( std::string&& n ) // see the double ampersand
```

*ctor 4* only accepts temporaries (**rvalues**) by reference.

> For constructor 3, the const reference parameter represents a constant that can accept a temporary value for initialization

Yes, it can bind to all the values as I mentioned previously.

> For Constructor 2:
> Instantiation 1 raises an error. The compiler complains that 'Candidate constructor not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument'

This is the expected behavior.

**Important Note:**

```
Cat(std::string&& n): name(n) { // here n is of type rvalue refernece to string
    std::printf("Call: Cat(std::string& n)\n");
}
```

Function parameters that are of type rvalue reference are lvalues themselves. So in the above code, `n` is a variable and it's an lvalue. Thus it has an *identity* and *can not be moved from* (you need to use `std::move` in order to make it movable).

#### Extra note:

You can even pass an lvalue to a function that only accepts rvalues like this:

```
Cat( std::string&& n );

std::string s("Mike");
Cat cat2( std::move(s) );
```

`std::move` performs a simple cast. It casts an **lvalue** to an **xvalue** so it becomes usable by a function that only accepts an **rvalue**.

#### Value Category in C++11

Take a look at this:
[image: Value Categories in C++11]

#### Explanation for the above image

> In C++11, expressions that:
>
> - have identity and cannot be moved from are called lvalue expressions;
> - have identity and can be moved from are called xvalue expressions;
> - do not have identity and can be moved from are called prvalue ("pure rvalue") expressions;
> - do not have identity and cannot be moved from are not used[6].
>
> The expressions that have identity are called "glvalue expressions" (glvalue stands for "generalized lvalue"). Both lvalues and xvalues are glvalue expressions.
>
> The expressions that can be moved from are called "rvalue expressions". Both prvalues and xvalues are rvalue expressions.

Read more about this topic at [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).